# How to get keyboard presskey values in a VB.NET 2005 application?

Tags: vb.net, keyboard

Hai How to get keyboard presskey values out of the application in vb.net 2005. I try form keydown event that is working in Application Active.

Answer (score 0):

I'm hesitant to help someone that is "doing Spysoftware", but it sounds like you're trying to create a [low level keyboard hook](http://blogs.msdn.com/toub/archive/2006/05/03/589423.aspx).  Code project has a [sample application and code](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/CSLLKeyboardHook.aspx).